# I am a 9 letter name. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am a 9 letter name.
>
> My first letter is silence.
>
> My 2nd, 3rd and 4th letters represent a current moment or time.
>
> My 5th, 6th and 7th letters spell an electronic component.
>
> My 5th, 9th and 8th letters become a body part.

Who am I?

Comment: You can also add a clue about the 3rd, 4th, 5th making a fowl.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is:

> Knowledge

My first letter is silence.

> K as Knee (same word in a riddle today .. lol)

2nd,3rd and 4th letters represent a current moment or time.

> Now

5th,6th,7th letters spell an electronic component.

> LED

5th, 9th and 8th letters become body part name.

> Leg

Comment: Powerful brain....

Comment: the first and second clues were the key for me

Comment: I only got LED and Leg. I kept think Day for 2nd, 3rd and 4th letters :l

Comment: Never skip leg day. You are right.

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer is

> Knowledge

Comment: Slighlty too late unlucky, +1 too though

Comment: @Beastly Yep Hard luck.

Comment: 42 seconds .. ^^' .. +1

Comment: @ Iois6b :) Gives you +1 for fast thinking

Answer (score 7):

It is:

> Knowledge

My first letter is silence.

> The "K" in knowledge is a [silent K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_k)

2nd,3rd and 4th letters represent a current moment or time.

> Now

5th,6th,7th letters spell an electronic component.

> LED

5th, 9th and 8th letters become body part name.

> Leg